# Physics book for 15 year old boy

Tags: soft-question, education, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of good classical physics books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/list-of-good-classical-physics-books)

my name is Bruno Alano. As stated in the title, **I'm 15 years old** (I'll do 16 on 7 of Feb) and much love **Computer Science** (C, C++), **Mathematics** and **Physics**.

Some information may have been unnecessary, but my question is: **What is the suggestion of a good physics book for a teenager of my age?** I know basic things (speed, shoveller these issues and basic primary and secondary).

A good reason for this is my Awe in mathematics and physics. Besides that maybe one day be useful in what I really want a career (science or computer engineering).

**And another question: It is interesting physics in the area I want to go? I'm at an age that would be good to learn beyond what is taught in common schools?**

Comment: - [Fundamentals of Physics by Halliday , Resnick , Walker](http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Physics-David-Halliday/dp/0471216437/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1327795032&sr=8-2) - Feynman's Lectures

Comment: that is the best combination of studying good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Physics for the Inquiring Mind: The Methods, Nature, and Philosophy of Physical Science" by Eric M. Rogers is a superb book for a teenager. It doesn't overwhelm the reader with esoteric mathematics and provides a very solid foundation which is often missing in so many books. Expensive at about 60 dollars , I found a copy for 15 dollars, so seek young man and ye shall find!

On Amazon: [Physics for the Inquiring Mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691151156)

Similarities in Physics - John Northrup Shive and Robert Weber is another great book for showing the interconnectedness in physics and basic ideas ranging from Simple Harmonic Motion, Heat, Noise etc. Actually I think this is one of the great and unknown pedagogical books for physics and it's free [here](http://www.ebook3000.com/Similarities-in-Physics_119097.html). you really can't go wrong reading that one.

If you like a laugh and the kooky then try Macschrödinger's Cat - Jim O'Brien also [at Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1460965019), but don't read this one for insight or learning, read this one just to stretch your mind.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it doesn't answer your question directly i think these videolectures are a great place to start and really motivating (and for free):

- Walter Lewin ot the MIT:
  http://web.mit.edu/physics/people/faculty/lewin_walter.html go to --> take a class Physics I, II, III
- Foundations of Modern Physics: Leonard Susskind
  http://academicearth.org/courses/foundations-of-modern-physics

Answer (score 1):

It is not a physics books, though this book will make you a physics lover.

[Surely You are joking Mr. Feynman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surely_You%27re_Joking,_Mr._Feynman!)

If you can get books for highschool that would be a good start, don't rush yourself, learning physics takes time and hard work.