# Phonon-polariton literature resources?

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, phonons, quasiparticles

What is a good resource for studying phonon-polaritons?

Comment: Hi tlengman, I am not sure if you are expecting a list as an answer to your question or if you would be happy with just some explained pointers to the relevant literature. Questions asking for a list are not a good idea here, maybe you should adapt the title a bit.

Comment: Hi tlengman, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This site is not really a good place for open-ended list questions like the one you're asking. If you can edit it to make a more specific request, I'll be happy to reopen it.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the tips.  I'll try to ask questions that are more relevant to the stackexchange model in the future.

Comment: I think asking about a recent review article concerning the topic would probably be ok (if you could edit this question) since it would not be asking for a list anymore. If you are done with editing you could ping a mod (with the @) and ask for reopen.

Comment: Thanks @Dilaton, do you think it would be okay to ask if anyone is familiar with the foundational literature?  Like the first paper published on polaritons?

Comment: I noticed this stackexchange question in the Related panel: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/list-of-good-classical-physics-books?rq=1

Comment: @tlengman I think asking about (a) very specific reference(s), such as the very first paper(s) published on polaritons should be ok, since [reference requests](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2918/2751) are allowed here. It would probably be a good idea to use the tag "reference-request" instead of "books" in this case. However, not that I have no power to reopen; I can just help agreeing that questions should be reopend ;-)