# What is the first paper to report observations of polaritons?

Tags: specific-reference, quasiparticles, phonons

I am seeking references to the first articles regarding the observation of polaritons.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/49749/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Yeah, I was asked to change the question and limit its scope. This question is similar, but fundamentally different, and hopefully more appropriate for the stackexchange venue.

Comment: Just to let you know the system, when you are asked to change the question (usually by a moderator, in this case @DavidZaslavsky), you are supposed to edit the [original question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/49749/2451), you are not supposed to create a new duplicate-like post.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I made this question in order to improve upon my first question, but Qmechanic let me know that I should have just altered the old question. What should I do now that I have made the new one? Should I delete this one or the first one, or just leave them both. They really are very different, they would require completely different answers etc.

Answer (score 1):

Found something today.

"Actually the concept of polaritons has been described in words as early as 1946 [F. Bloch, Phys. Rev., 70, 460 (1946)] in nuclear paramagnetic resonance, however without using the then still unkown term 'polariton'."

Klingshirn, Claus F., Jul o6 2012, Semiconductor Optics
Springer Berlin Heidelberg, Dordrecht, ISBN: 9783642283628