# Reference request for motion & related topics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm starting a Robotics course at grad school and I could use some help to relearn and revise my concepts in the following topics :

1. Kinematics
2. Rigid Body Dynamics
3. Rotational Motion and Linear Momentum
4. Force

Could you good people please let me know of 
1) the best (subjectively speaking) intuitive sources that helped you learn the concepts?
2) some sources that showed examples instead of verbose explanations ?

Any help/suggestions much appreciated! Thanks.
(if there are any more specifics required, please let me know, I will edit the post)

Comment: Hi Raaj, you're asking for too much here.  Your list of 4 topics it awfully broad, especially your 4th one "force".

Comment: Probably any first year physics course book that contains exercises would suffice. It's about practicing with the exercises anyhow, not about the precise explanations.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Apologies for not looking thoroughly or having skipped the above links.

But @BrandonEnright , thanks for mentioning the links. They serve my purpose just fine. Thank you.