# I need a good book for learning mechanics in non-inertial frames

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, reference-frames, inertial-frames

I'm studying classical mechanics, but without those stuffs Lagrangians and Hamiltonian mechanics...just Newtonian..the problem is a find hard to learn this non-inertial frames system, like $r=R+r'$...only that I find difficuly, because they say "the absolute vector is the sum of the distance between the origins and the relative vector of the rotating system", but how can I add two vector of different basis systems? How can I say after I add these two vectors of different basis axis, and say that the result, belongs necessarily to the first basis system? Can anyone tell me about a book that goes deep into this with a good amount of graphics and examples?

Comment: If you like lectures notes,look at David Tong lectures which explain these stuff very beautifully.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate because noninertial reference frames are covered in general Newtonian mechanics books, and you can find a few lists of those in the general book recommendations question. Also @Paul, you might want to post that as an answer on one of those other questions, where it's appropriate.

Comment: And I find your answer inapropiate. Because I'm clearly having issues about how this topic is faced in most of newtonian mechanics with little to not deeper study and perpective...all books are different, I'm looking the best in this particular topic....bad asnwer

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/2451

Comment: I think $r = R + r'$ is an abriviated notation. Doesn't make sense otherwise as you pointed out.