# Looking for a calculus based physics book

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, calculus

Ive gotten through University Physics by freedman et al and I realised i really enjoy the calculus problems in them which involve integrating infinitismal element (moment of inertia, charged rods, shell theorem, etc). Can anyone recommend a book that places heavy emphasis on such infinitismal element calculus?

Comment: Related (if not a dupe) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/25301 (see also linked within)

Answer (score 0):

classical mechanics by David Kleppener,Vibrations and waves by A.P French, Principles of electromagnetism by Matthew N.O.Sadiku. Dont know any books for Modern Physics though. Also go through the classic "Fundamentals of Electromagnetism" by Irodov