# Newtonian Mechanics Textbook

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I am preparing for the F=ma Physics Test and I was wondering if anyone could recommend a book on Newtonian Mechanics at a college level textbook based on algebra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommendations for good Newtonian mechanics and kinematics books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/)

Comment: I see that this is really late, and that this thread has not been very helpful to you. I am commenting to help some others who may be preparing for the F=ma exam. There is a lot of physics book recommendations here:https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Physics_books Also, i doubt you will find a good physics book with problems that is algebra based. You have conceptual physics, and thats it. I suggest that you learn calc, and then go through Morin's Intro to Classical Mechanics Book.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend Goldstein's classical mechanics
Available at: [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201657023)

Also check out Classical Mechanics By T. W. B. Kibble, Frank H. Berkshire
[Google Book's Link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0a8dk0eDxgEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=classical%20mechanics%20college&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL67jo3ILYAhUEKcAKHTSxCtUQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=classical%20mechanics%20college&f=false)

Enjoy!

Comment: These are not college-level, algebra-based textbooks.