# How to get into Classical Mechanics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I hope you are all doing fine! I'm a 14 year old student from the UK, and have been really interested in theoretical physics, but before I reach that I need to build on more basic knowledge. So I set out to learn calculus and some linear algebra, mostly from Khan Academy and 3B1B's videos on the topic. However, I can't find much content for Classical Mechanics online. Are there any websites or maybe textbooks that you can recommend me, so that I can further my knowledge on this subject!

P.S. The last time I asked my teacher if he could point me in the right direction, he just told me to keep my head down, but I know I am capable of learning complicated concepts, it is not beyond me :)

Comment: Also, for anyone wondering, I have looked for physics textbooks in PDF form online, and I did find Griffiths and Taylor's book online, but I'm really confused at bits of what they are saying and want a slightly more gradual progression into C.M.

Comment: Classical mechanics is really heavy on the mathematical side and, although I don't doubt that you could understand something, basic calculus and linear algebra from courses given by Kahn Academy and 3B1B won't suffice the slightest. I recommend that you first learn in a deeper way (from textbooks and university level courses which you can easily find on youtube) calculus (multivariable at least), and more fundamentally, differential geometry, and some complex analysis does not hurt.

Comment: To just have a taste of what I mean, the go-to book on classical mechanics is Arnol'd book.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks so much @DavideMorgante, I will try and focus more on the maths side first then, that may be a better idea. I think physics is interesting in the sense that without maths, physics doesn't make too much sense. THanks

Comment: Your interest at such a young age should be encouraged. I suggest you search the internet for university first year coursed on physics. These typically start with mechanics. Alternatively you could have a look at the first few lectures of https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/ and see how far you get. If this is well above your level, go back to more math first.

Comment: Thanks @Oбжорoв, I will take a look at those courses, they seem nice!#