# What Mechanics textbook can I use for these topics for my exam?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I have a big problem with Mechanics. Can someone help?

My Mechanics III exam is in two weeks and it will cover the following topics. What mechanics textbook can I use for reading the these topics?

1. ***Motion in 2 - dimensions (Use of Polar Coordinates)***
2. ***Circular Motion***
3. ***Conical Pendulum***
4. ***Constrained Motion in a circle (and vertical circle)***
5. ***Simple Harmonic Motion***
6. ***Motion in a resisting medium***

- - *Vertical Motion under Gravity*
  - *Damped Harmonic Motion*
  - *Projectiles in resisting motion*
  - *Variables Mass Motion*

7. ***Dynamics of Rigid Bodies***

- - *Product of Inertia, Principal axis*
  - *Momental Ellipse, Virtual work and D'Alembert's Principle*

I must say that I've never known Mechanics. I used to memorise formulas for objective exams. But this time around, it's in theory and that won't work.

The lecturer recommended **A Shorter Intermediate Mechanics** by *Humphrey and Toppings.*

I've gone through this textbook and it was not explanatory for me at all.

I also did my own research and checked these textbook:

- ***Goldstein Classical Mechanics***
- ***University Physics***
- ***Classical Mechanics*** by *John R. Taylor*

Of the three, I only found University Physics to be explanatory to an extent.

I'm searching for something that is more explanatory than it and is also self-explanatory.

Please, can you recommend textbooks or videos or anything that can help?

*At this point, I'm frustrated and I would have given up but I want to try my best and also avoid guilt conscience.*

I really appreciate any help I get in advance.

***This is an example of what my exam questions look like.***

[image: 1]

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've seen most of the books there before. I'll check the rest. I think I'll manage University Physics for now.

Comment: IMO the only thing "wrong" with Humphrey and Topping's books on mechanics is that they were written 60 or 70 years  ago - before the internet killed off most students' ability to learn something by actually *reading* books, rather than looking at pretty colored diagrams and watching YouTube videos.