# Preparing for an examination - Kinematics & Dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, resource-recommendations, education

I am preparing for an examination and would like to know some good resources for the following topics in the image. I would like resources from which I can build a concrete understanding, practice examples, exercises.:

[image: These are the topics.]

Any resources is appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming your institution provides resources and recommendations already. We can't give you resources for a whole syllabus of topics, you need to ask a specific question.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/2451 and links therein.