# Best Physics textbook to get a full understanding of classical mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm in university and have studied physics in high school as well but every textbook I have read is some incomplete part of classical mechanics and always leaves me with more questions. I'm looking for a textbook that handles motion in all three dimensions and goes in-depth on classical concepts both the math and physically meaning behind these concepts enough so that you could very well describe most system around you. If anyone knows of anything like this that would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/2451 and links therein.

Comment: _Classical Mechanics_ by Herbert Goldstein.

Comment: Try Classical Mechanics by Taylor