# A good classical (Newtonian) mechanics book for Undergrads

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I have looked across the book recommendations wiki, but haven’t found a suitable book. Could someone suggest a book for Newtonian Mechanics. (beginner+advanced undergrad as well; it could be a series as well)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/2451 and links therein.