Mechanics textbook advice
I am currently looking for a good textbook on Newtonian mechanics but am unable to find anything that suits my specific needs. I have already done an advanced high school mechanics course and would like to take a more sophisticated look at the subject over the summer, in preparation for a course in analytical (Lagrangian and Hamiltonian) mechanics that I will be taking in university in the fall. The options that I have been considering so far are Halliday and Resnick, Kleppner and Kolenkow and Morin. All have their pros and cons. Halliday and Resnick seems to be too basic for my needs; from what I understand, it's meant to be a first introduction to Newtonian mech (among other topics in physics). Kleppner and Kolenkow is much better in that regard; however, the book (at least the 2nd edition) is ridden with typos and mathematical errors to the point that, 30 pages into the book, I got really pissed and decided to switch to Morin. Morin is pretty cool, but some of those problems are really insane. Additionally, he leaves out certain parts in his explanations and makes logical leaps that he expects the reader to understand on his own, which cognitively is quite difficult for me handle.
Can anyone suggest any other good mechanics textbook? I am looking for something that goes beyond standard introductory mechanics but does not go to the Morin extreme of insanely difficult problems and unclear explanations, some kind of intermediate option. I thought that would be K&K but ended up quite disappointed... Or perhaps could someone give me advice on how to go about studying Morin?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6068/2451 and links therein.
